# how can i compress and increase performanceof this loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails:
from URL i want to get a specific value,  for that one i am checking  whether the url containing that value or not using an array. if it has that value i am splitting url and returning value.

```
@url = 'http://fruits.com/A15/abc1234-apple-w740_h550_q58.jpg'

['apple','banana','grape','butter','honey'].each do |fruit|
  if (@url.include? fruit) 
    return @url.split(fruit)[1].freeze 
  end
end
```

i don't want to loop 5 times..
question is how can i compress this loop.

Comment: You can only `return` from a method. Besides, what is your expected result?

Comment: "w740_h550_q58.jpg" this value i want to return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a regular expression to [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-split):

```
@url = 'http://fruits.com/A15/abc1234-apple-w740_h550_q58.jpg'

@url.split(/apple|banana|grape|butter|honey/)[1]
#=> "-w740_h550_q58.jpg"
```

Or, using [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
@url[/(apple|banana|grape|butter|honey)(.*)/, 2]
#=> "-w740_h550_q58.jpg"
```

Or, using a [positive lookbehind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) to avoid the second argument: (hat tip to mudasobwa)

```
@url[/(?<=apple|banana|grape|butter|honey).*/]
#=> "-w740_h550_q58.jpg"
```

Comment: regex works much faster than any loop with attributes in array. This should be an answer.

Comment: Or, without ugly `, 2`: `@url[/(?<=apple|banana|grape|butter|honey).*/]`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
url = 'http://fruits.com/A15/abc1234-apple-w740_h550_q58.jpg'

['apple','banana','grape','butter','honey'].select { |f| url.include? f }
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
@url = 'http://fruits.com/A15/abc1234-apple-w740_h550_q58.jpg'

def last_part_of_url
  fruit = ['apple','banana','grape','butter','honey'].detect { |f| @url.include?(f) }
  @url.split(fruit).last if fruit
end
```